# How to parse I. {text} II. {text} III. {text} IV. {text}

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I parse (in JavaScript with regex) into array string with pattern:

> I. {text1} II. {text2} III. {text} IV. {text2} ...

(it is known that Roman order numbers from I-VII)

Comment: Is this one line? What *exactly* do you want to parse? What should the result look like?

Comment: `txt.match(/{((?!}).)*}/g)`

Comment: @Mr_Green clever, but it is not yet decided if the OP's string actually has the { and } characters at all, or if they just added those in for the question.

Comment: @Mr_Green why would one use the negative lookahead in a single-character case? `/{[^}]*}/g` And good point @JoeFrambach

Comment: @m.buettner yup I was not sure. that is why I commented. thanks

Comment: or else `txt.match(/(?!\.)\s((?!\s).)*\s/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this:

```
var result_set = your_string.match(/[IVXLDMC]+\. {.*?}/g)
```

Example:

```
your_string = "I. {text1} II. {text2} III. {text} IV. {text2}";
your_string.match(/[IVXLDMC]+\. {.*?}/g)
["I. {text1}", "II. {text2}", "III. {text}", "IV. {text2}"]
```

Comment: This will not correctly identify roman numbers - it'll treat `VIV` as a number, which is not.

Comment: According to OP - it's given that the numbers are correct Roman numbers.

Comment: @AleksG if you want to be more restrictive, you need to specify which version of roman numerals you want. Is `IIII` a valid number, or only `IV`? You know, it appears on most clocks. Is `IM` a valid number, or only `CMXCIX`?

Comment: Also, there is no need for the non-greedy quantifier. It won't change the result, but hinders performance

Comment: non-greedy is needed not to match everything by the very first ".*"

Comment: Sorry, I meant the non-greedy quantifier on the character class.

Comment: @mishik the first non-greedy is not neccessary for that purpose

Comment: And for the second one `[^}]*` is the more efficient and more explicit alternative

Comment: `IIII` is not a valid Roman number, but `IV` is.  If you want to be correct, here's a regex to match only valid Roman numbers: `/M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})/`

Comment: I wonder if the OP's string actually has the `{` and `}` characters at all, or if they just added those in for the question. OP is being very quiet.

Comment: @AleksG now compose a regex for the extended roman numerals (where `IM` is allowed)

Comment: No there are no {}, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "I. {text1} II. {text2} III. {text} IV. {text2} ...";
text.split(/ ?[IV]+\. /)
```

This outputs:

```
["", "{text1}", "{text2}", "{text}", "{text2} ..."]
```

It's quick and dirty, and you can [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the first empty element off.

Comment: What about when it gets to *X*, or *L*, or *M*?

Comment: This will treat `VIV` as one of the numbers - and fail.

Comment: The question states "(it is known that Roman order numbers from I-VII)"

Comment: 1 - 7 aren't the only numbers that *can* be represented by that numbering system.

Comment: We're not solving for the general case here. We're solving for the OP's input.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Your regex will match non-numbers and split on them if something like that is in the text.

Comment: The original question is too vague to deduce if that's intended behavior or not.

Comment: Thank you, actually this simple solution will to work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

From [that site](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/diveintopython3/html/regular-expressions.html):

```
M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})
```

Should detect any of your roman numbers

Use it to get the indexes with roman numbers, and then use the substr or substring methods to get your texts. Or use split:

```
text.split(/ M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\./) // split with  <space>RomanNumber<point> separator
```